# How to get data that belongs to specific user?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a list of exams and it is only assigned to each user to whom it is assigned but the problem is. all exams are visible even if they are not assigned to the user.

I have a list of exams and it is only assigned to each user to whom it is assigned but the problem is. all exams are visible even if they are not assigned to the user.

```
<?php
function get_data($query){
    $conn = db_connect();
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $output ;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $output[$row['id']] = $row;
    }
    return $output;
}  
    session_start();
    $title = "ExamList";
    $query = "SELECT id, title, no_questions, points, schedule, time_limit, link FROM exams";
    $exams = get_data($query);
?>

<?php foreach($exams as $exam){?>

                        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
                            <div class="card border-round pink-gradient exam_card">
                                <div class="card-body text-center">
                                    <h4><?php echo $exam['title']; ?></h4>

                                    <div class="btn-group dropright float-right">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                                            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu border-round pink-gradient dropdown_body">
                                            <a href="examinees_result.php?id=<?php echo $exam['id']; ?>"
                                                class="card_link">View</a>
                                            <hr>
                                            <button id="copy" class="copy_link"
                                                data="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$proj_name."/exam.php?link=".$exam['link'];?>">Copy
                                                Link</button>
                                            <hr>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a "WHERE" param to your query.
Now you are trying to select each exam from the database instead of selecting the ones assigned to the user

Example

```
SELECT id, title, no_questions, points, schedule, time_limit, link FROM exams WHERE user_id = 1
```

Change "user_id" parameter to one from your database or create it in order to assign exam to student. And you should dynamic replace "1" with ID from user session.

https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_where.asp

Comment: And, architecturally speaking, this is probably a good place for a `STUDENT_EXAMS` table and an `INNER JOIN` because there is probably a "one to *many"* relationship between exams and students – not "one to one."  I refer you to online tutorials to learn exactly what I mean.